# Unable to create a test and training set using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here's the code I've been working on.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
housing_data = load_boston()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_set, test_set = train_test_split(housing_data, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
```

And I get this error.

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2057 
   2058     return list(chain.from_iterable((safe_indexing(a, train),
-> 2059                                      safe_indexing(a, test)) for a in arrays))
   2060 
   2061 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in <genexpr>(.0)
   2057 
   2058     return list(chain.from_iterable((safe_indexing(a, train),
-> 2059                                      safe_indexing(a, test)) for a in arrays))
   2060 
   2061 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in safe_indexing(X, indices)
    162             return X[indices]
    163     else:
--> 164         return [X[idx] for idx in indices]
    165 
    166 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    162             return X[indices]
    163     else:
--> 164         return [X[idx] for idx in indices]
    165 
    166 

KeyError: 3
```

Comment: I notice you have asked 11 questions, 10 of which have at least one answer, many of them with a few upvotes, yet you have not accepted any of them. You should consider [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and marking answers that solved your problem as accepted so people know your question has been answered.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru, thank you for telling me something about this community I've never heard of. And, I'll accept the suitable solutions right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for `load_boston()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_boston.html) you'll see it returns a `Bunch` object. If you inspect that object in Spyder's variable explorer you can see it contains a description, the actual data (the features you can make your predictions from), the labels for each of those features, and the target vector containing the value you're trying to predict.

[image: load_boston]

You can instead run the following if you're looking to only get the data portion (the data features for prediction):

```
train_set, test_set = train_test_split(housing_data.data, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
```

Alternatively, you can create training and test sets for both X and y (features and target) with the following:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(housing_data.data, housing_data.target, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
```

Which yields the following set of variables:

[image: boston train_test_split]

**Edit:** If you call load_boston() with the `return_X_y = True` parameter, it returns a tuple of `(data, target)`, allowing you to do the following, which is arguably more elegant:

```
X, y = load_boston(return_X_y = True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
```